# Embedding scriptblock in another scriptblock

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, nested

I am using kendo ui and trying to dynamically load my template from an external htm file.
As to the kendo specification i can achieve this by wraping that content into a identified script block. Further I would need to additionally serve a javacript code for some logical ui stuff.

In chrome, the engine interprets the first upcoming script endnode () as the endnode for the root script node. So that does not work..

How could I solve that and serve the script as needed?!

```
<script id="layout-template1" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <div id="wms-content"></div>
   <!-- We need this script to use modify height for the layout wrapper -->
   <script>
     var pN = document.getElementById("wms-content").parentNode;
     pN.style = "height:100%";
   </script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to put your `script` inside that `script` tag, because it will cause redundant function and hard to debug when you use it with repetitive element like list or grid.

Instead you could put those `function` in external javascript file, then call the `function` when the template being injected e.g event `dataBound` on grid/list view.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Do you got any example or pseudo code to show? :)